# React Native Navigation - Bottom tabs position absolute

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

My bottom tab navigator is set to absolute position with background trasparent,
but when i go to the map Tab i want the tab to change from posision absolute to relative
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can render your own component with any position.

Comment: no i mean when i press the tab icon i want in this particular screen the whole tabBar to go from absolute position to relative

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you, Any example?

Comment: i Have a Tab.Navigator with 3 tabs. Lets say First Tab is Home, second Tab is Map and third Tab is settings. I have set barStyle to position absolute for all tabs at Tab.Navigator but when i want to go to Map tab Screen i want the Tab to not be absolute(i want the whole tab to be absolute transparent only on Home and settings)

Comment: then what happens after pressing the second tab?

Comment: When i press the second tab it navigates me to Map tab Screen..I want the whole Tab.navigator to be absolute and transparent only when i am in Home Tab and Settings Tab and i want to change Tab.Navigator to static/relative while in Map Tab

Answer (score 0):

Try `navigation.isFocused()` or

```
const {name} = useRoute();
const position = name === 'Map' ? 'absolute' : 'relative';
```